# How to convert date to the date of the Monday of the date in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Assume 2022-10-01 and 2022-10-8 are Monday, and the original table looks like this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-03 | x |
| 2022-10-04 | y |
| 2022-10-09 | z |

I want to convert it to

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | x |
| 2022-10-01 | y |
| 2022-10-08 | z |

Is there any simple ways to do this? Thanks!

I tried look up but seems not finding anything neat solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`date_trunc`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?truncation-function) function. For example:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('week', dt)
FROM (
    VALUES DATE '2022-12-01'
) t(dt)
```

output:

```
   _col0
------------
 2022-11-28
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is great to know, thanks Martin!

Answer (score 0):

You want to truncate the date. This will depend on your SQL dialect, but you tagged Presto so I [looked it up](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) in their documentation.

I think you want

```sql
    SELECT
        truncate_date(week, Date) + interval '1' day AS date,
        Value
      FROM
        table
```

(I've hedged a bit here and added a day, because I assumed it will truncate to the preceding Sunday. Do experiment with that!)

Comment: Good to know there is a built-in function for that, thank you so much Paddy!